# Configure Spring Data Redis to perform all operations via Elasticache configuration endpoint?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster, spring-cloud-aws, amazon-elasticache

**Description**

Is it possible for Spring Data Redis to use Elasticache's configuration endpoint to perform all cluster operations (i.e., reading, writing, etc.)?

**Long Description**

I have a Spring Boot application that uses a Redis cluster as data store. The Redis cluster is hosted on AWS Elasticache running in cluster-mode enabled. The Elasticache cluster has 3 shards spread out over 12 nodes. The Redis version that the cluster is running is 6.0.

The service isn't correctly writing or retrieving data from the cluster. Whenever performing any of these operations, I get a message similar to the following:

```
io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: MOVED 16211 10.0.7.254:6379
```

In searching the internet, it appears that the service isn't correctly configured for a cluster. The fix seems to be set the [spring.redis.cluster.nodes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.redis.cluster.nodes) property with a list of all the nodes in the Elasticache cluster (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41918747/3362244) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59289359/how-to-connect-aws-elasticache-redis-cluster-to-spring-boot-app)). I find this rather needless, considering that the Elasticache configuration endpoint is supposed to be used for all read and write operations (see the "Finding Endpoints for a Redis (Cluster Mode Enabled) Cluster" section [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Endpoints.html)).

My question is this: can Spring Data Redis use Elasticache's configuration endpoint to perform all reads and writes, the way the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Endpoints.html) describes? I'd rather not hand over a list of all the nodes if Spring Data Redis can use the configuration endpoint the way its meant to be used. This seems like a serious limitation to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found works:

```
@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory()
{
  LettuceClientConfiguration config = 
    LettucePoolingClientConfiguration
      .builder()
      .*your configuration settings*
      .build();

  RedisClusterConfiguration clusterConfig = new RedisClusterConfiguration();
  clusterConfig.addClusterNode(new RedisNode("xxx.v1tc03.clustercfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com", 6379));

  return new LettuceConnectionFactory(clusterConfig, config);
}
```

where xxx is the name from your elasticache cluster.